# Get SUM between daterange using UNION

Tags: php, mysql, union

I want to get sum of each table between two dates from multiple tables group by each date.
my code fetches only one score, And not getting sum of all score for each date.

```
SELECT z.dates
   COALESCE(a.allscore) AS cricket_score,
   COALESCE(b.allscore) AS football_score
   FROM (
   SELECT dateby AS dates FROM cricket_table
   UNION
   SELECT dateby FROM football_table) AS z
   LEFT JOIN (SELECT dateby AS dates, SUM(score) AS allscore FROM cricket_table
            WHERE dateby BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-03-03'
           GROUP BY dates) a USING (dates)
   LEFT JOIN (SELECT dateby AS dates, SUM(score) AS allscore FROM football_table
            WHERE dateby BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-03-03'
           GROUP BY dates) b USING (dates)
GROUP BY z.dates
```

[complete code with database structure]

```
$sql = "
create table cricket_table  (player varchar(50), score int, dateby date);

create table football_table  (player varchar(50), score int, dateby date);

insert into cricket_table values
('Sohail',32, '2020-01-02'),
('Saleem',65, '2020-01-02'), 
('Hamid',76, '2020-01-02'),

('Sohail',33, '2020-05-02'),
('Saleem',44, '2020-05-02'),
('Hamid',22, '2020-05-02');

insert into football_table values 
('Sohail',1, '2020-01-02'),
('Saleem',2, '2020-01-02'),
('Hamid',3, '2020-01-02'),

('Sohail',6, '2020-05-02'),
('Saleem',7, '2020-05-02'),
('Hamid',8, '2020-05-02');
";

$result = $db->prepare($sql);
$result->execute();

$query = $db->prepare("SELECT z.dates
       COALESCE(a.allscore) AS cricket_score,
       COALESCE(b.allscore) AS football_score
       FROM (
   SELECT dateby AS dates FROM cricket_table
   UNION
   SELECT dateby FROM football_table) AS z
   LEFT JOIN (SELECT dateby AS dates, SUM(score) AS allscore FROM cricket_table
                WHERE dateby BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-03-03'
               GROUP BY dates) a USING (dates)
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT dateby AS dates, SUM(score) AS allscore FROM football_table
                WHERE dateby BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-03-03'
               GROUP BY dates) b USING (dates)
    GROUP BY dates
");
$query->execute();
echo '<table><tr><th>Player Name</th><th>Cricket</th><th>Football</th></tr>';
while($row = $query->fetch(PDO:: FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
    echo '<tr>
        <td>'.$row['player'].'</td>
        <td>'.$row['cricket_score'].'</td>
        <td>'.$row['football_score'].'</td>
     </tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

(https://pastebin.com/prvsd1X8)

Comment: Why do you have separate tables apparently storing the same kind of thing, and what would the desired result look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as you want date-wise cricket_score and football_score
check the below query if it meets your expectations

```
SELECT dateby, SUM(cricket_score) AS cricket_score, SUM(football_score) AS football_score
FROM (

SELECT c.dateby, c.score AS cricket_score, 0 AS football_score 
FROM cricket_table AS c 
WHERE c.dateby BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-07-05' 

UNION

SELECT f.dateby, 0 AS cricket_score, f.score AS football_score 
FROM football_table AS f 
WHERE f.dateby BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-07-05'

) AS temp GROUP BY dateby
```

A simple and easy approach

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/fc606/15

output

```
dateby       cricket_score   football_score
2020-01-02    173             6
2020-05-02    99              21
```

Comment: yes, but in his PHP code he want to show player-wise cricket_score and football_score only

Comment: @Strawberry 'LEFT' removed

Comment: sorry for that mistake. I want date-wise not player-wise, I have used this method before. It hangs mysql server.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few minor issues:

1. Missing comma after `z.dates` in the first line
2. You have no default value for the `COALESCE` function for when `allscore` is `NULL`
3. Your range of dates in the subqueries (`BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-03-03'`) does not include all the dates in `cricket_table` and `football_table`
4. You don't need a `GROUP BY` on the outer query.

So your query should look like this:

```
SELECT z.dates,
       COALESCE(a.allscore, 0) AS cricket_score,
       COALESCE(b.allscore, 0) AS football_score
FROM (
  SELECT dateby AS dates FROM cricket_table
  UNION
  SELECT dateby FROM football_table
) AS z
LEFT JOIN (SELECT dateby AS dates, SUM(score) AS allscore 
           FROM cricket_table
           WHERE dateby BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-05-03'
           GROUP BY dates
           ) a USING (dates)
LEFT JOIN (SELECT dateby AS dates, SUM(score) AS allscore 
           FROM football_table
           WHERE dateby BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-05-03'
           GROUP BY dates
           ) b USING (dates)
```

Output for your sample data:

```
dates       cricket_score   football_score
2020-01-02  173             6
2020-05-02  99              21
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=364ed942b783915437e56d81078604b7)

Comment: could you do it in [phpfiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/). by using exact query as you edited it fetches all dates between the range.  and by adding `WHERE z.dateby BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-05-03' GROUP BY z.dates` to the outer query. it fetches correct data but repeating same dates, And not getting it grouped.

Comment: @Eniol I'm not sure what you mean. If you could edit your question with the expected result from your query that would make it easier to figure out how this does not meet your needs.